# Close File Error when pulling data into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary

I am trying to pull the data in the csv file below into a dictionary, but my code returns an operation on closed file error.

[image]

```
LotrGrade = {}

with open('grade_list_large.csv', 'r') as FOpen:
    line = FOpen.readline()
    LotrGrade = {}


for line in FOpen:
    grades = []
    line = line.rstrip()
    Name = line.split(',')
    NameKey = Name[0]
    GradeValu = list(Name[1])
    while True:
        if NameKey in LotrGrade.keys()== True:
            LotrGrade.setdefault(NameKey).append(GradeValu)
        else:
            LotrGrade[NameKey] = GradeValu

    else:
        False
        print(LotrGrade)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1**

```
  with open('grade_list_large.csv', 'r') as FOpen:
        line = FOpen.readline()
        LotrGrade = {}
```

---

At this point, you close the file `FOpen1` after the indented block. If you check the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html),

> It is good practice to use the with keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way

So you can't access `FOpen1` in this line

```
for line in FOpen
```

to read the lines in the file because you've already closed it.

**Issue 2**

The following statements don't make any sense

```
with open('grade_list_large.csv', 'r') as FOpen:
    line = FOpen.readline()
    LotrGrade = {}
```

Essentially, you open a file, read one line from it to `line` and closes it. As of now, you have just read the very first line from the file. 
If you modify these statements to

```
with open('grade_list_large.csv', 'r') as FOpen:
    lines = FOpen.readlines()
    LotrGrade = {}
```

You can later on loop through `lines` as

```
for line in lines:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you use the `with` keyword to open a file it will automatically close the file at the end of the `with` block.

So the error is happening at `for line in FOpen:` because FOpen has been closed.

Two approaches to fix this, either move all the logic into the with statement (this would keep the file open while the script runs), or parse the data out of the file and into a list before the file is closed (open the file to read data then close it).  I'd prefer the latter, but it's up to you.  Here's an example of the second approach.

```
data = []
open('grade_list_large.csv', 'r') as FOpen:
    for line in FOpen:
        data.append(line)
    LotrGrade = {}

for d in data:
    # do some work
```